# Get the top ID in each group in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

i want to add a column that contains the first in each group.

Sample:

```
Product       ID
Orange        1
Orange        2
Orange        3
Orange        4
Apple         5
Apple         6
Apple         7
Grapes        8
Grapes        9
```

Desired output:

```
Product       ID
Orange        1
Orange        1
Orange        1
Orange        1
Apple         5
Apple         5
Apple         5
Grapes        8
Grapes        8
```

Comment: Apple: 5, 5, 7 ? , kinda confusing.

Comment: `MIN(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY Product)` will do the trick. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3867/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Product)`:

```
SELECT Product, 
       ID = MIN(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Product)
FROM dbo.Products
ORDER BY ID
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1fa69/2/0)</kbd>

Article from today: [Understanding the OVER clause](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Over+Clause/132079/)

Comment: Yeyyy! Thanks! Got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Tim correct!
Other case, you can use:

`SELECT P.Product
FROM dbo.Products P
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.Products WHERE Product = P.Product ORDER BY ID)`